# Site search with options while searching

Tags: django, search, django-haystack

I'd like to create a search on my site like dividata.com has. That means, it only searches by stock symbol and stock name and users may select something only if there exists a record of it? How can I do that? Can you point me to an article or something where I may find information how to do it? 
I'm using django on openshift. I looked at haystack and elastic search, but it looks like integration of elasticsearch on openshift won't be that easy. But I think I don't need something as complex as elasticsearch. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help if you are looking for autocomplete search bar, I've solved that but I have problem with something else.
[Django-haystack full text search working but facets don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662916/how-to-use-django-haystack-facets)

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing me to haystack autocomplete, suggestions and facets. Now I've moved to boostrap search view. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21705372/django-haystack-autocomplete-with-bootstrap